# BIRT to Excel cell formatting

Tags: excel, birt

I have a report in BIRT that in Excel, a particular cell shows "0.%" and not "0%".
In pdf, i can see the cell set to just "0%".
Back to excel, the value of the cell is really "0%", but the cell is retaining the format it got from BIRT, which is "0.##%" in excel and BIRT, that's why it shows this unwanted writing of "0.%".

How do I overcome this?

Comment: Do you always want to round up/down to the nearest integer or only in this instance?

Comment: only in this instance. i dont want any cell to contain "0.%" or "30.%", but other cells must contain "30.25%"

Comment: Hm. Strange behaviour. I'd expect it to show 0.00 then. Which locale do you use?

Answer (score 0):

well, i did transform the field into String, and managed to display the format as i want.
i used parseInt(x) versus parseFloat(x) to dertermine whether i need to use

```
importPackage( Packages.java.text );
var sdf = new DecimalFormat("###,##0.00");
```

or not. and finally, i displayed the result as string concatenation with "%"